# Moving code from BPM to ESB

Tags: mule, esb, business-process-management

We have an application that uses BPM for managing long running processes.
We don't want to use this product anymore and we're looking at moving it to an ESB (i.e. Mule).

My view on this is that complex and long-running processes don't belong in an ESB. Also it would need to manage state which is not what an ESB should be doing in my opinion. An ESB is designed to handle high-volume, short-lived, real-time type messages? Am I correct in saying this?

Does anybody agree/disagree with this and what would the best solution be?
For example, should the BPM code be rewritten as a java application with a database behind it to manage state and use maybe quartz in Mule to handle periodic tasks to replace timers that are used in the BPM application?

I'd be interested to hear as many opinions on this as possible.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case you can move to an ESB if 3 characteristics are met:

1. the BPM solution was used for very low level messaging (EAI).
2. there is no much instrumentation of the data for business users, for example through a BAM module to represent KPIs and enforce SLAs.
3. there is no human interaction, for example through forms, workflows, approvals.

You can use ESB to move messages across systems. If you need to capture and track state, you probably want to use a database to keep it in sync. You can also enforce some level of transaction support via queue systems like JMS.

You probably need to have a good idea how to move things over. A good idea is to overlay the BPM with a thin layer, and then replace it without disrupting the user experience.

I hope this helps. Disclosure: I am the Chief Architect of Intalio, a BPM company.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a little late to the party here :), but I will write for the benefit of those who come here looking for an answer...

This is what Ross Mason has to say about the ESB BPM discussion.

> Mule 3 provides strong orchestration capabilities with Flow, which is
>   great for short-lived transaction where the goal is to maximize
>   throughput and scalability. For other use cases like long running
>   transaction, Mule has support for commercial and open source BPM
>   products (like jBPM, Activiti, BonitaSoft BPM, etc.).

So yes ESB and BPM are complimentary solutions and not substitutes for each other.

To conclude, I guess you are correct about your observations.

[Source](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/run-mule-run-mule-3-1-is-out/)